# Create an item in sharepoint calender when infopath form is submitted in sharepoint 2010 through workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a scenario where i have vacation request which is a infopath form when submitted workflow kicksoff and the date item should be updated in calender and if it is deleted the item should be deleted from calender .what approach can i follow to do this.